# Sending and receiving AJAX requests with Ext js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I need to sending and receiving AJAX requests with js and PHP
what the problem in my code ?

php code

```
function pingAddress($ip) {

    $pingresult = exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);

        if ($status == 0) {
             return "online";
        } else {
            return  "offline";
        }
    }
```

js code

```
function ping(ipAddress) {

      Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: urlApp + 'pcs/pingAddress/ipAddress',
      success: function(e){
              alert(e.responseText);
        } ,  
      failure: function(){
               Ext.Msg.alert("Massage");
        }
       });
}
```

Pls help my

Comment: I don't know. What is not working as you expect it to?

Comment: As Mike pointed out, in order to help you, we need more detail about what is currently happening for you with this code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good  if you had an error message.
In the mean time...in your javascript code, it seems you do not send the ipAdress.

Try this, it may solve you problem:

your url should be:

```
urlApp + 'pcs/pingAddress/ipAddress?ipAddress=' + ipAddress
```

or maybe

```
urlApp + 'pcs/pingAddress/' + ipAddress
```